# isset($_POST['submit']) not working

Tags: php, isset

if condition is not working here. 
i've gone through the earlier solutions but i didn't find a right solution . 
i couldn't understand the reason .
please help me out

```
<?php
require'core.inc.php';
require'connect.inc.php';
include 'header.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $query="INSERT INTO college (CollegeName) VALUES ('".$_POST['college']."')";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    header('Location:index.php');
}
?>

<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="college">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

 <?php include'footer.php';?>
```

Comment: Set name as submit....

Comment: You should use mysqli_* instead of mysql_* functions; they're deprecated and susceptible to injection.  As for your question, you have two value attributes on your input button.  It needs a name="submit" attribute.

Answer (score 11):

You have two `value` here in `<input>`, 1 at least should be `name`. Also there is no `<button>`, so remove the `Submit</button>`.

```
 <input type="submit" value="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                      ^^^^^          ^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

should be

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, this method is not the best practice for it doesn't work on Internet Explorer. At the time of writing these i had tried it on IE 8. I find most programmers using this method for one reason or another. My two coin cents would be to check if a POST method has been requested. Please see how you could approach it below.

`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
//if a request has been made, do something. Example post or email your data
}`